# Modifiying dimple layout grouped chart

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I am using the same chart as below. I want to push the x-axis headers i.e. Regular, Premium, Budget little bit below i.e. top padding or margin. Give some styling to it like give background color and change text color.  I tried using fill and it does not work as desired. I would like to hide Price Tier/Channel also

http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical_grouped

Answer (score 0):

These are SVG text elements so there is no top-padding or margin.  You can move them down a bit by increasing the y property though, running the following after you call the `chart.draw` method will move the labels down 5 pixels:

```
d3.selectAll(".dimple-axis-x .dimple-custom-axis-label")
  .attr("y", function (d) { 
      // Get the y property of the current shape and add 5 pixels
      return parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + 5; 
   });
```

To change the text colour you need to use the fill property (again that's an svg text thing):

```
d3.selectAll(".dimple-axis-x .dimple-custom-axis-label")
  .style("fill", "red");
```

To colour the background of the text is a little less trivial, there actually isn't a thing for that in SVG, however you can insert a rectangle behind the text and do what you like with it:

```
d3.selectAll(".dimple-axis-x .dimple-custom-axis-label")
  // Iterate each shape matching the selector above (all the x axis labels)
  .each(function () {
      // Select the shape in the current iteration
      var shape = d3.select(this);
      // Get the bounds of the text (accounting for font-size, alignment etc)
      var bounds = shape.node().getBBox();
      // Get the parent group (this the target for the rectangle to make sure all its transformations etc are applied)
      var parent = d3.select(this.parentNode);
      // This is just the number of extra pixels to add around each edge as the bounding box is tight fitting.
      var padding = 2;

      // Insert a rectangle before the text element in the DOM (SVG z-position is entirely determined by DOM position)
      parent.insert("rect", ".dimple-custom-axis-label")
         // Set the bounds using the bounding box +- padding
         .attr("x", bounds.x - padding)
         .attr("y", bounds.y - padding)
         .attr("width", bounds.width + 2 * padding)
         .attr("height", bounds.height + 2 * padding)
         // Do whatever styling you want - or set a class and use CSS.
         .style("fill", "pink");
      });
```

These three statements can all be chained together so the final code will look a bit like this:

```
d3.selectAll(".dimple-axis-x .dimple-custom-axis-label")
   .attr("y", function (d) { return parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + 5; })
   .style("fill", "red")
   .each(function () {
      var shape = d3.select(this);
      var bounds = shape.node().getBBox();
      var parent = d3.select(this.parentNode);
      var padding = 2;

      parent.insert("rect", ".dimple-custom-axis-label")
         .attr("x", bounds.x - padding)
         .attr("y", bounds.y - padding)
         .attr("width", bounds.width + 2 * padding)
         .attr("height", bounds.height + 2 * padding)
         .style("fill", "pink");
      });
```

FYI the `dimple-custom-axis-label` class was added in a recent release of dimple so please make sure you are using the latest version.  Otherwise you'll have to find an alternative selector